# What is the correct punctuation usage for 'thus' in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas, syntactic-analysis, semicolons, colons

**"They believe technology serves humankind by empowering us with access to information and the ability to spread that useful information; thus, enriching our lives."**

Comment: I can't think of any plausible rationale for preceding "thus, enriching our lives" with a semicolon. The least-intrusive punctuation choice might be this: "They believe technology serves humankind by empowering us with access to information and the ability to spread that useful information, thus enriching our lives." Evidently, "thus" is being used in the sentence in the sense of "thereby" or "in that way," in which case you don't need the comma after "thus" either.

Answer (score 3):

> They believe technology serves humankind by empowering us with access to information and the ability to spread that useful information, thus enriching our lives.

The word "thus" in this sentence serves as an adverb which modifies the entire sentence. It's not a conjunctive adverb because the piece of information it introduces is not a complete sentence or an independent clause. Here, "thus" is a plain adverb and, like other adverbs that modify phrases or clauses, should be introduced with a comma.

See other examples:

He pressed down hard on the brake, thereby bringing the car to a stop.

Her hand slipped as she attempted to replace the box, accidentally bringing down the entire shelf.

He worked faster, duly noting the approaching deadline.